# How to make consecutive requests in Redux-Toolkit with proper error handling

Tags: redux-toolkit

In my application, when the root component mounts, I fetch a list of books. After that, it must auto select the first book of the list and fetch its list of chapters. And after that, auto select the first chapter and display its details. After the initial load, the user is capable of selecting another book or chapter within the current book.

Suppose there's a network problem or bad API response when I fetch the book list. What's the best way to abort the remainning actions and just display a notification message? I've been using something like this:

```
import requestChaptersList from './chapterSlice'

// ...

const requestBooksList = createAsyncThunk(`${sliceName}/requestList`, async () => {
    return await api.books()
}

export const requestBooksListAndChapter = () => async (dispatch) => {
    await dispatch(requestBooksList())
        .then(unwrapResult)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(selectFirstBook())
            dispatch(requestChaptersList())
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch(notifyError(error))
        })
}
// ...
```

The problems are:

1. `unwrapResult` creates a serialized version of the original error. But my `notifyError` (ideally) is supposed to get an Error object or a subclass.
2. Without `unwrapResult`, the `requestBooksList`'s reject reducer is run, but the `.then` ppart continues normally.
3. It does not seem to scale well when the number of requests increases. For instance, if I wanted a Book > Chapter > Page sequence.